# Find all possible values of $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> If sum of the squares of two numbers is $a^2$ and the product of these numbers is $a^2  +2a  + 2$, find all possible values for number $a$.

So, $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ and $xy = a^2 + 2a + 2$.

$x^2 + y^2 + xy = 2(a^2 + a + 1)$

But any hints?

**EDIT,**

I think they might be integers, but I dont know for sure, this is the problem QUOTED.

But anyway,

$(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = a^2 + 2(a^2 + 2a + 2) = 3a^2 + 4a + 4 \implies x + y = \sqrt{3a^2 + 4a + 4}$

Let $P(t)$ be a quadratic hence,

$P(t) = t^2 + \sqrt{3a^2 + 4a + 4}t + (a^2 + 2a + 2)$

The solutions to this gives $x, y$.

But this is very messy!

**EDIT 2**

I got that:

$xy = (a + 1 - i)(a + 1 + i)$ then let $x, y$ correspond to each product, thus,

$x^2 + y^2 = (a + 1 + i)^2 + (a + 1 - i)^2 = 2a^2 + 4a = a^2$

So I got, $a^2  + 4a = 0, a = -4$. Which are both wrong answers.

Comment: Are $a,x,y$ integers?

Comment: @user236182, no clue, I would assume so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve it in real numbers.

$$(x-y)^2\ge 0\iff x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$$

$$\iff a^2\ge 2a^2+4a+4$$

$$\iff a^2+4a+4\le 0$$

$$\iff (a+2)^2\le 0\implies a=-2$$

because $(a+2)^2\ge 0$ for all real $a$.

The problem only asked for $a$, but we can find $x,y$:

$xy=2\iff y=\frac{2}{x}$ (clearly $x,y\neq 0$), so $$x^2+y^2=4\implies x^2+\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^2=4$$

$$\implies x^4-4x^2+4=0\iff \left(x^2-2\right)^2=0\iff x=\pm\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: So the assumption that $x$ are $y$ integers is wrong. However, knowing that $a = -2$ allows $x,y$ to be solved for completely.